# How to set an image to RelativeLayout Background

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with 2 `Button`s inside.

One `Button` has `layout_alignParentLeft="true"` property and the other button has `layout_alignParentRight="true"`

I want set a background on my RelativeLayout that show an image in the middle. I have a `play.9.png` in my drawable and use following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/play" // background line
 >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAbout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="but1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="but2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when i use background line, my `Button`s miss their position

See the image below
[image]

But i want my `RelativeLayout` be like this:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: can you please upload the `play.9.png` image ? even your code works fine for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally i do it guys
i used this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/play" // background line
 >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAbout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="but1" />

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="but2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my result was like:

[image]

and this works. thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp" 
android:background="@drawable/play" // background line
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAbout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="but1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSync"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="but2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no, its doesnt work. unfortunately my Buttons Horizontal position is missed too

Comment: try giving the button layout height to 70dp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

from both the buttons and set the button height to 'fill_parent'.